# Most concise and proper way of avoiding cross thread operation error?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am not pretty good at delegates and I don't get what's happening under hood. I get the `cross thread operation` error when accessing UI items from a different thread.

What I want to do is write a generic function in a `Utility` class so that I pass can any method/code block to the function. I can do it many ways like:

1. ```
   delegate void UpdateGui(Control c, Action action);
   public static void Do(Control c, Action action)
   {
       try
       {
           if (c.InvokeRequired)
           {
               UpdateGui updaterdelegate = new UpdateGui(Do);
               c.TopLevelControl.Invoke(updaterdelegate, new object[] { c, action });
           }
           else
               action();
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           //throw ex;
       }
   }
   ```
2. ```
   public static void Do(Control c, Action action)
   {
       try
       {
           if (c.InvokeRequired) 
           {
               c.TopLevelControl.Invoke((Action)delegate { Do(c, action); });
           }
           else
               action();
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           //throw ex;
       }
   }
   ```
3. ```
   public static void Do(Control c, Action action)
   {
       try
       {
           if (c.InvokeRequired)
           {
               c.TopLevelControl.Invoke(action);
           }
           else
               action();
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           //throw ex;
       }
   }
   ```
4. ```
   public static void Do(Control c, Action action)
   {
       try
       {
           if (c.InvokeRequired) 
           {
               c.TopLevelControl.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => action()));
           }
           else
               action();
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           //throw ex;
       }
   }
   ```
5. ```
   public static void Do(Control c, Action action)
   {
       try
       {
           if (c.InvokeRequired) 
           {
               c.TopLevelControl.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { action(); }));
           }
           else
               action();
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           //throw ex;
       }
   }
   ```
6. ```
   public static void Do(Control c, Action action)
   {
       try
       {
           if (c.InvokeRequired) 
           {
               c.TopLevelControl.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { action(); });
           }
           else
               action();
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           //throw ex;
       }
   }
   ```

I believe approaches 1 and 2 are essentially the same, and 4, 5 and 6 as well. My questions are:

1. What's the difference between approaches (1 & 2), 3 and (4, 5 & 6)? I mean what would be the cases where one handles/takes care of which other does not?
2. What's the proper way of avoiding `cross thread operation` error, in the sense it handles all the situations, preferably concise and readable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "third" approach above (just using the `Action`) is simpler and more efficient.  Your other approaches using `delegate` create a separate method (anonymous method via the `delegate` keyword) which then calls your original delegate (the `action` parameter), which is unnecessary.

The 3rd option just directly uses the `Action` passed in, which is simpler.

The first option is similar, though in that case, you're passing in values that aren't necessary (the `Control`) plus having to define a custom delegate (though you could use `Action<Control,Action>` instead).  As the Control isn't being used, there is no reason to add this complexity.

On a side note - when you rethrow within your exception handler, it'd be better to just use `throw;` (and not `throw ex;`), as this will preserve the stack trace properly:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Do whatever, ie: logging
    throw;
}
```

If you're not going to log, and just plan to rethrow, you can leave out the `try`/`catch` entirely.

Comment: I was more confused with `MethodInvoker`.. what special thing is it doing in place of `delegate`, `action`, `() => ` keywords?

Comment: @nawfal It's just another delegate declaration.  Effectively, it's the same as using `Action`.  The `=>` syntax is a lambda expression, which is the newer syntax for making an anonymous method (similar to `delegate { }` but with cleaner syntax).