# Find as you type error backgroundworker in C# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, backgroundworker

I have the following form where I am trying to implement an incremental search on, using a `backgroundworker`.

[image: Winform]

So the idea is the user types in the `textbox` at the top, and for each keystroke, the `listview` below is filtered to contain only the items that contain the characters the user has typed.

I have recently learnt about the `backgroundworker` component and was therefore trying to use it to do the filtering and updating the `listbox`.

This is the event code for the `textbox`:

```
 private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
     {
         backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
     }
 }
```

and the `backgroundworker` event is:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    if (txtSearch.Text != String.Empty)
    {
        GetTheListOfFiles();
        listView.Items.Clear();  << Exception occurs here !

        ...... //some more code to populate the listview control            
    }
}
```

**PROBLEM**

When I type into the `textbox`, I was expecting the `listbox` to respond immediately to my keystrokes and display the filtered data accordingly. Instead, there is a pause of about 8 seconds and then I get this error:

[image]

I presume the issue is the bit that I have highlighted, but I have no idea how to solve it. Is it that a `backgroundworker` cannot be used for this purpose or am I missing something in my implementation?

PS: I welcome any different way to accomplish this. Perhaps there's a better solution out there among more experienced programmers?

**UPDATE**

Here is the `progresschanged` event I am using:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    toolStripProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    tsLabelTwo.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + @"%";
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the)

Comment: The DoWork event of the BackgroundWorker lives in a different thread than the UI controls that you are trying to update. This is a well known problem and if you want to update your control you need to raise the ProgressChanged event that runs in the same thread of the UI

Comment: Thanks Steve, ive added the progresschanged event code. Newbie question: How do i know what thread that will run on? cheers

Comment: Try like this for access http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14019054/how-to-changing-listview-inside-backgroundworker-cross-thread-error

Comment: I am not sure to understand your question.  Knowing what thread will run what? The backgroundWorker1_DoWork runs in a thread that is not the same thread where your listview control has been created. So if you try to access that reference you will face the problem. ProgressChanged should switch the context back to the UI thread and let you do your updates. You can even pass parameters to this ProgressChanged that you can use in the event handler (like the result of your GetListOfFiles)

Answer (score 0):

If you create a control using the UI thread, you can't access it thought another thread (eg some background thread)

Just invoke the block that is throwing cross-thread exception on the main thread:

```
listView.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { listView.Items.Clear(); }));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update UI, you need to invoke the control:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

        if (txtSearch.Text != String.Empty)
        {

            GetTheListOfFiles();
            listView.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => listView.Items.Clear()), DispatcherPriority.Background);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are trying to a control that runs on UI thread from another thread you've created, which is considered illegal. The correct workaround for this is to invoke your control, in this case your ListView.

```
listView.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => 
{ 
    listView.Items.Clear(); 
    //or perform your UI update or whatever.
}));
```

But if you wanna be such a rebel and do illegal stuff (sarcasm), add this piece of code right after your InitializeComponents(); method in the form's constructor.

```
Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
```

But don't, there is a reason it is called "Illegal Thread Calls" :)

For more information [Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.checkforillegalcrossthreadcalls(v=vs.110).aspx)